# Node.js conditional require

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider plugin `c` is supported in recent versions of Node.
What would be the best way to conditionally load it?

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [   
    require("a"),
    require("b"),
    [require("c"), { default: false }] //only if node version > 0.11
  ]
};
```

Comment: thousands of ways to conditionally load it. what are your specific requirements?

Comment: @self "//only if node version > 0.11"

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you add the [`semver`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver) package as a dependenc, then:

```
var semver = require("semver")
var plugins = [   
    require("a"),
    require("b"),
  ];

if(semver.gt(process.version, "0.11")){
    plugins.push(require("c"));
}

module.exports = {
  plugins: plugins
};
```

This code checks for the node version using `process.version`, and appends the required plugin to the list if it is supported.

Comment: Was thinking about a similar approach.
Although  `process.version` is 'v4.1.x' not sure the  `>` operator works well on strings

Comment: the `>` operator will work on strings, but may not produce what you expect when you're not dealing with numbers.

Comment: Yep, my mistake. `"0.9" > "0.11"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure the `major` part of the version number is 0 and the `minor` part of the version number is greater than 11 you could use this

```
var sem_ver = process.version.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '').split('.');

if(parseInt(sem_ver[0], 10) == 0 && parseInt(sem_ver[1], 10) > 11)) {
    // load it

}
```

Comment: major is also relevant as we don't want 1.09 to load the module. only versions prior to 0.11

Comment: +1 as I think it would work in conjunction with bigblinds answer. 
Interested to see if there are other ways of doing it. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You could use `process.version`:

```
var subver = parseFloat(process.version.replace(/v/, ''));

module.exports = {
  plugins: [   
    require("a"),
    require("b"),
    (subver > 0.11) [require("c"), { default: false }]
  ]
};
```

Comment: is setting `default = false` going to prevent importing the module ?

Comment: Oh I don't know, just put the condition in the whole property: `(process.version === 'v0.11') [require("c"), { default: false }]`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is check the [`process`](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.12/api/process.html#process_process_version) object. According to the documentation, it will give you an object like so:

```
console.log(process.versions);

{ http_parser: '1.0',
  node: '0.10.4',
  v8: '3.14.5.8',
  ares: '1.9.0-DEV',
  uv: '0.10.3',
  zlib: '1.2.3',
  modules: '11',
  openssl: '1.0.1e' }
```

Then, simply process out the `node` property into a conditional if in your object.

Comment: thanks. `process.version` and `process.versions` provide info about the node version. I am interested if there are multiple  ways to use this for conditionally loading modules